# How do I properly make my button execute my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a animation to happen when I click `Create an account` but for whatever reason it doesn't want to do anything it's as if it can't find the JS or something. and I have no idea why.

It should execute a fading effect when the `Create an account` text is clicked.

```js
$('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like it works to me based on just clicking it - I saw the form animate and now it asks to create an account instead of singing in

Comment: Your snipped was missing the **jQuery** library, I've added it and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do it, I'm on Chrome

Comment: Works for me exactly as expected... Login form fade and slides down, signup form fades in and slides up in the same place. Is there anything else on the page interfering with the JS? (any errors in your console when you click the button?)

Comment: It may be hard to see in a small viewport because of the anchor link navigation. Try adding `event` as a parameter in your `click()` function and then add `event.preventDefault();` before your animation line. This may help you see more clearly what is happening.

Comment: Oh my.. I had the script loading before the actual element so it didn't find it. Appreciate all the help!